# What do you call a person who easily communicates with others?

Tags: vocabulary, adjectives

I mean the type of person who likes to communicate with others and does so easily, and joins group activities easily.
Could one call him a "social person"?

For example: "I'm a social person"

Someone was using it in a discussion, but I was not sure if it was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *social person* is perfectly correct. Or here is a brief list of synonyms you could also use.

- (noun) a *social person*
- (adj) *social*
- (noun) a *socialite*
- (noun) an *extrovert*
- (adj) *extroverted*
- (noun) a *social butterfly*
- (adj.) *outgoing*

Comment: I don't think "socialite" is an appropriate word here. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/socialite). A socialite is a member of the leisure class who spends significant amounts of time entertaining and attending entertainment rather than working.

Answer (score 2):

I would call this person an *extrovert*. But you can definitely use *social person* as well.

Answer (score 2):

Common terms are:

sociable

outgoing

friendly (not exactly the same meaning, but often used that way)

gregarious (not very commonly used)

Answer (score 2):

"Social Person" sounds odd to me.

"I'm a people person", "I'm good with people" or "I'm a social butterfly" all sound better to my ear.

Answer (score 0):

Such a person could be described as a "communicative" person.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for snooping! But I think *communicative* is more realistic to describe the ability to communicate with others, so it's a skill, and not necessarily describes the personality which requires more than that because it's combination of bunch of aspects and skills therefore using phrases like *social person* and *extroverted* or even *butterfly* would be perfect in description of that type of people.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by giving reference for the information you are giving.